# IIS maximum worker processors and Signalr

Tags: signalr, iis-8, signalr-backplane

I have been having a lot of trouble to get Signalr to function reliably with messages inexplicably never arriving but being sent from the Hub almost as if the groups are being lost although the websocket connection is open on two clients which I am trying to communicate between.

I noticed now that I have IIS 8.5 set at 10 maximum worker processes for the site and they are all running.

Is this possibly a cause for the erratic behavior? Should I implement a backplane even if I have just one server but multiple processes?

Any help will be much appreciated. It's been weeks. :(

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Let me try rephrase it. If you're running multiple worker processes in IIS in InProc mode, does Signalr treat each process as a separate context?

Comment: I've dialed it down to one worker process and SignalR works correctly.